# issue with getting back to Mac after following: Create a bootable USB stick on macOS

Tags: boot, mac

I have created a bootable USB stick following the Create a bootable USB stick on macOS guide, howerver now i am stuck that i can not access my mac. I have not formatted my mac. it seems like the bootloder took over. I have tried various ways to get back to mac but it is not happening. i have tried the efibootmgr https://github.com/vathpela/efibootmgr-devel. Please help

thanks

Comment: If you did not format your Mac, then you should be able to remove the USB stick from the port and reboot. If this does not resolve the issue, then you did some part of the installation process, and specific details will need to be known.

Comment: Thanks for your response Matigo. Unfortunately, the only thing that I did was follow these instructions https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview. I then took out the USB so that i can go back to my mac and Ubuntu became the default OS. I know for sure I was working directly from the USB.

Comment: those instructions only lead you up until booting from the USB. Booting from the USB does not install Ubuntu on your Mac. You have done something else (ie, clicking "install Ubuntu" after you booted from the USB) if you have Ubuntu on your Mac without the USB inserted.